# Cannot delete podcast from iPod Touch

Tags: itunes, ipod, ipod-touch

I am having a problem with my iPod/iTunes where an episode of a single podcast cannot be deleted.  The episode in question does not show up in iTunes or as being on the iPod when I drill down and look at the podcasts on the iPod in iTunes.  It also does not play if I try to play it on the iPod; it just waits a second and skips to the next podcast.

I have iTunes 9.2.0.61, my iPod has OS version 4 (although I was having this problem before I upgraded), and Windows 7 64bit.

I would really prefer a solution that does not require me to completely wipe the iPod because I have a bunch of WiFi keys stored that I don't want to have to dig up again.

Comment: I'm not clear on something: how are you attempting to play it if you can't see it anywhere on the iPod or in iTunes? Where are you playing it from?

Comment: I can see it on the iPod itself, but when I connect to iTunes and iTunes lists what is on the iPod it does not show up there.

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to figure this out myself.

I had some luck to delete about half of the episodes that weren't showing up by changing the media type to "Music" instead of "Podcast".

Also in order to get the "hidden" episodes to show up in iTunes you can put them in a playlist, but this still doesn't allow you to delete them from the iPod.

Unfortunately this only worked for half of the episodes in question. The other half refuse to change their media type to music for some reason!